# EF Core AsSplitQuery not respecting OrderBy

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am using EF Core to query my DB. As I have some includes i get this warning

> Compiling a query which loads related collections for more than one collection navigation either via 'Include' or through projection but no 'QuerySplittingBehavior' has been configured. By default Entity Framework will use 'QuerySplittingBehavior.SingleQuery' which can potentially result in slow query performance. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2134277 for more information. To identify the query that's triggering this warning call 'ConfigureWarnings(w => w.Throw(RelationalEventId.MultipleCollectionIncludeWarning))'

so when i add `AsSplitQuery()`

```
public async Task<Board> GetBoardAsync (Guid id) {
            return await _context.Boards.Include (x => x.Lists.OrderBy(x => x.Order))
                  .ThenInclude (x => x.Items.OrderBy(x => x.Order))
                  .AsSplitQuery()
                  .FirstOrDefaultAsync (x => x.Id == id);
        }
```

OrderBy is not respected when returning data.

How to overcome this warning and respect OrderBy

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
public async Task<Board> GetBoardAsync (Guid id) {
            return await _context.Boards.Include (x => x.Lists.OrderBy(x => x.Order))
                  .ThenInclude (x => x.Items.OrderBy(x => x.Order))
                  .Where(x => x.Id == id)
                  .AsSplitQuery().FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        }
```

Also, you can use `AsNoTracking()` for queries to better performance.hope it will resolve your issue.

**UPDATE**

Use `ThenBy` instead of `OrderBy` because [ThenBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.thenby?view=net-5.0) works for several sorting criteria.

Comment: nope still the same Order is not respected

Comment: @Damien I updated my answer. please check.

Comment: 'ICollection<List>' does not contain a definition for 'ThenBy' and no accessible extension method 'ThenBy' accepting a first argument of type 'ICollection<List>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [API]csharp(CS1061)

Comment: OrderBy on Lists is not respected is what i can see.

Comment: @Damien I thought so,  seems to be specific to OrderBy.

Comment: there is any other way to make it split?

Comment: @Damien first of all, you can try globally use spilt and then you can try using order by.

Comment: but how to do that?